# Installing Cloudera Manager on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to install Cloudera Manager in a Google Compute Engine Ubuntu 12-04 instance. Everything works fine until the installation step.

The error occur when tries to detect the Cloudera Manager Server. It seems an error with the hostname... the report error is the next one:

```
could not contact scm server at 236.193.155.104.bc.googleusercontent.com:7182, giving up 
waiting for rollback request
```

Screenshot:

[image: error output from Cloudera Manager]

Please someone help me with this! I'm working on it for too long time and I feel that it is not complicated to resolve..

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you resolve your issue yet? If not, you can now use [Cloudera Director on Google Cloud Platform](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/cloudera/director/quickstart) which will help install Manager and the rest of CDH or EDH. It should be much easier to do it this way. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Add the firewall exception for your instances to allow tcp connections on port 7182 through them.The following is the command that allows all the tcp connections.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create cloudera-manager --allow tcp
```

Reference:  Hadoop on GCE http://github.com/scalding-io/hadoop-on-gce/blob/master/build-cluster

Answer (score 0):

To help with deploying Cloudera Manager, I wrote [these scripts](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/cloudera/manager) which may be of use to you, as they simplify the installation and deployment of Cloudera Manager on Google Compute Engine.

Also, you can now use [Cloudera Director](https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/tree/master/apps/cloudera/director/quickstart) to deploy and provision Hadoop clusters on Google Cloud Platform. Cloudera Director is a single server binary which can deploy and manage other VMs to install Cloudera Manager as well as the rest of the Cloudera Hadoop distribution automatically with an easy-to-use GUI.